# Why can the masses of the Higgs and top quark determine whether we live in a false vacuum?

Tags: mass, vacuum, higgs, quarks

I read in the paper linked below that the ground state of the universe depends on the potential of the Higgs field, particularly the graph of the Higgs potential with its minima and maxima. I think I understand why the Higgs is important, because it gives fundamental particles their mass, but what about top quarks?

[Paper I read](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v8/108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Higgs potential receives quantum corrections from the Yukawa couplings with fermion doublets. The magnitude of the correction is determined by the Yukawa coupling constant, which is itself proportional to the fermion mass. As a result, the heaviest fermions make the greatest contribution to the effective action. Because the top quark is by far the heaviest fundamental fermion, quantum corrections due to top quark loops have the greatest effect on the Higgs effective potential, so to a good approximation only corrections due to top quark loops need to be accounted for.

The details of the Yukawa corrections and their effects on vacuum stability are reviewed in section 2 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06923) (for transparency, it's written by my PhD supervisor).